# How can the backend know what users are doing in a client made in next.js?

Tags: laravel, next.js

The backend of the application is in laravel and the frontend is written in Next.js taking advantage of server components.

Currently, the auth is handled via JWT, that is emitted once by the server and stored client side. In the mobile application, the JWT token is manually attached to every request in the authorization header to the server after the user is logged in. This way, the back-end can know what the user is requesting, how much he is requesting etc.

But in next.js the back-end isn't requested at all. The user is is requesting the node server that is returning an already cached version of what he needs. The next.js app, in other words, is serving many users having make just one single request to the back-end API.

This obviously has many advantages, but in this case, how can the back-end API know what the users are doing? What are some possible ways that it can track what the user is doing in the next.js app?

Comment: Have you considered storing your data in cookies? Cookies are sent from the client to the server and from the server to the client on every HTTP request.